# Node BigQuery apiResponse is always undefined

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm using the **BigQuery API** of the Google Cloud Node library
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/bigquery/0.9.0/bigquery

According to the official documentation, the callback function of the "query" method should return an object named **apiResponse**.

However, I'm always getting the value

```
undefined
```

I tried to query the dataset and the bigquery object directly, but I had the same response.

I need this information in order to get the cost of the executed query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug not yet solved:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36408121